# Rails App: How do I use a simple search method to search through associated models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, associations, rails-activerecord

Ive been using a simple search method to implement a search feature for several parts of an app im using. The methods and controller index actions look like this.

Index action ( participants_controller.rb )

`def index
  if params[:search]
    @participants = Participant.search(params[:search])
  else
    @participants = Participant.all
  end
end`

Participant Model ( participant.rb )

`def self.search(terms)
  if terms
    where("email ILIKE ?", "%#{terms}%")
  end
end`

The issue im having is that I need to not only search by email ( which is how the self.search method is set up now. ) But I also need to search by first and last name ( f_name, l_name ). but this info is in an associated model called ParticipantDetail.

Ive tried the following but I get a 'no method participant_detail' error

`def index
  if params[:search]
    @participants = Participant.participant_detail.search(params[:search])
  else
    @participants = Participant.all
  end
end`

Ive also tried searching like this...

`def index
  if params[:search]
    @participants = ParticipantDetail.search(params[:search])
  else
    @participants = Participant.all
  end
end`

But this is actually no good because it only brings up the associated record and not the belonged_to (parent ) record.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ParticipantDetail belongs_to :participant`, and `Participant has_one :participant_detail`, use an `INNER JOIN`

```
Participant
  .select('participants.*')
  .select('participant_details.f_name, participant_details.l_name')
  .joins(:participant_details)
  .where('participants.email ILIKE :search OR participant_details.f_name ILIKE :search OR participant_details.l_name ILIKE :search', search: terms)
```

Comment: i get the following error on the first select line

private method `select' called for "the_term_i entered":String

Comment: `select` isn't a private method. Make sure you're calling it on `Participant`, which needs to be an ActiveRecord model (not a plain ruby class)

Comment: I implemented your solution wrong. I tried it exactly as you have it and now I get... 

now i get 

Can't join 'Participant' to association named 'participant_details'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Ive played with the spellings and plurality and It doesnt seem to matter. I still get this error. :/

Comment: ok nevermind. Thank you. This is the solution. The ":participant_details" had to be written singular.

Comment: The 2 most common join types are `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`. DB joins basically create a "punnet square" based on the 2 input tables, and every combination of output. 100 records joined with 100 records joined with 100 records could yield 1 million rows. That is where the `WHERE` clause comes in. It's hidden in your code when you write `joins()` but if you look at the SQL query output in console you will see its only showing the records out of that million where `participant_details.participant_id = participants.id`

Comment: The easiest way to understand JOINS is to use a visual SQL editor (Sequel Pro and Postico on OSX), and manually type a bunch of queries in until it 'clicks'. Its not intuitive at first, then it makes perfect sense once you get it.

Comment: I mean `ON` not `WHERE`. `ON` is used to tell what records to show when the tables are joined, and `WHERE` is used to filter those results even further

Answer (score 1):

In your `search` method you can add the following:

`joins(:participant_detail).where("participant_detail.f_name ILIKE :search OR participant_detail.l_name ILIKE :search OR email ILIKE :search", :search => "%#{terms}%")`

and use `@participants = Participant.search(params[:search])` to call it.

Comment: on the @participants.each do line of the view i get the following error

`code`
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "participant_detail"
LINE 1: ...ls"."participant_id" = "participants"."id" WHERE (participan...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "participants".* FROM "participants" INNER JOIN "participant_details" ON "participant_details"."participant_id" = "participants"."id" WHERE (participant_detail.f_name ILIKE '%kiana%' OR participant_detail.l_name ILIKE '%kiana%' OR email ILIKE '%kiana%')`code`

Comment: `code`
<div class='container paddingbottom'>
    <% @participants.each do |participant| %>
      <%= render 'participants/participant_card', :participant => participant %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
`code`

I apologize for the formatting. im struggling to figure out this mini-markdown for comments

Comment: the line that triggers the error is the "@participants.each do" line